# Getting node way relationship from Osm2pgsql data

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I would like to ask what is the best way to extract which way a node belongs to given a Postgresql databased generated by Osm2pgsql.

For example, in https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/4961890042, **node_id of 4961890042** gives two ways **Farmington Road (59440591)** and 
**Farmington Road (506461412)** and I would like to have similar results by performing SQL query.

I've read some materials, it is possible that a separated table can be created by defining the style file. The current style I used is default.style and it looks like query `public.planet_osm_rels` is not a good idea.

Comment: It seems that you have used the slim option and you have now osm_nodes, osm_ways and osm_relations tables, is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is right, I used the --slim option and have the above tables.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I would like to do the quite same...